# Time-out tempdb

Tags: sql-server, jobs, tempdb

When the job is running, it takes a time-out error. Usually it works, sometimes get any errors.

Job schedule : Occurs every day 3 minute

> Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 3 for page (9:307344), database ID 2. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 845).  The step failed.

tempdb splited eight. Because, my server cpu eight core.

`DBCC PAGE (2,9,307344)`

> DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your
>   system administrator.

I tried tempdb autogrow option %10 percent and 100 mb.

When I'm researching, it sounds like an IO problem. But I do not know what to do.

Comment: when a latch timeout occurs, there will be a minidump created .. you can spend time trying to debug using WinDbg or you can call MS for support. See this for help - https://mssqlwiki.com/2012/09/07/latch-timeout-and-sql-server-latch/

Comment: The old dump files not show any problems. I will try to read the dump file when the problem is repeated. Thanks for your comment.